# thrusters, force torque, distribution matrix , orbit maneuver

Tags: orbital-mechanics, spacecraft, propulsion, low-earth-orbit

I have a few questions about computing torques and forces.

I use the same configuration as in the thesis titled [An Attitude Control Sysytem Design Based on the Turksat-1b Geostationary Satellite](https://books.google.nl/books?id=q1ocdDBsm3MC&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=%27An+Attitude+Control+System+Design+Based+on+the+Turksat-1b+Geostationary+Satellite&source=bl&ots=fxAdiI9XXy&sig=j9KV_fgdcp5qxvO6FBMKdUlnXWI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsh-aNhdPbAhVCXBQKHZ_kD-AQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q='An%20Attitude%20Control%20System%20Design%20Based%20on%20the%20Turksat-1b%20Geostationary%20Satellite&f=false).

The thruster orientation and the location of the model are mentioned in Table 3-4-5, pages 53-55, and I use the equations 4.19a, 4.19b, 4.19c, but I don't get the same value as it mentions in Tables 4-5.

I used the equation (4.19b) to calculate the force Fx, but I didn’t get the same results.

Is this the right way [image]to compute the force???

```
FX=10*cos(0)cos(-16)=9.6126
```

[image]

Comment: If you have a link to that paper, it would be nice to add it to the question. That said, table 5 is in not consistent with tables 3 and 4. Table 5 is merely table 4 with an extra place of precision rather than $\vec r \times \vec F$.

Comment: https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ae.metu.edu.tr/~oderman/OzgurDerman_ThesisFinalDraft_Dec1999.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiqnvSc4tbbAhUCWSwKHS_UA2oQFjACegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3vMSKicivO3dsWcH80lfRA

Comment: https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ae.metu.edu.tr/~oderman/OzgurDerman_ThesisFinalDraft_Dec1999.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiqnvSc4tbbAhUCWSwKHS_UA2oQFjACegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3vMSKicivO3dsWcH80lfRA

Comment: Page 53 54 55 please check the table

Comment: The tables are inconsistent. That happens, even in the best of publications. That's why even the best of publications publish corrections, also known as "errata". The torque from a thruster (table 5) must be the vector cross product of the displacement vector from the center of mass (table 3) and force (table 4). That's a **must be**,  but in this case, that isn't the case. Scientific papers appear to violate the laws of physics with great regularity due to bad writing, bad editing, or bad peer review.

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate you comments/suggestions.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly send me some publications related to this topic